# Consistent text size for one line

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have an element with 1 line of text and I don't want it to overlap the border or start a new line. So I was considering using a limit on the length of text allowed, do all characters use an equal amount of space across browsers?

Comment: No, different browsers, fonts, and OSs all contribute to subtle differences. If you want consistency, use an image.

Comment: The element will hold user input

Comment: is your problem with the text overflowing its text containing element..can u edit your question and show your code..

Comment: There is no code yet, I was just wondering how text needs to be managed if it will have a known limit to characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all letters are the same size, it is dependant on the font type. Individual settings on browsers also play a factor.

To see a list of fonts with the same size see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces